# A bag contains 2 red, 3 green and 2 blue balls. Two balls are drawn at random. What is the probability that none of the balls drawn is blue?

Tags: probability, statistics, permutations, combinations

A bag contains 2 red, 3 green and 2 blue balls. Two balls are drawn at random. What is the probability that none of the balls drawn is blue?

I am helpless regarding this. I don't know how to solve it. My teacher asked me to solve it by finding the probability that the balls drawn are blue and then subtracting it from 1. But I want to solve it straight forward and directly. Is it possible? If yes, how?

Comment: Yes, what is the probability that the first ball is green or red ? The same for the second ball. Btw, is the first ball put back in the bag ?

Comment: Please be more specific.

Comment: Can you answer the first question of my comment ? Please be more specific.

Comment: yes, 5/7 i think.

Comment: Right. Is the first drawn ball put back in the bag ?

Comment: No.it is not so.

Comment: Then in total there are 6(=7-1) balls left. And 4(=5-1) non-blue balls. What is now the probability that the second ball is not blue ?

Comment: 4/6=2/3 i think

Comment: Your thoughts are right. Now multiply the probability and you´ll get the final result.

Comment: 10/21. Is it ok?

Comment: Yes. You can check by using the converse probability. One minus the probability that two blue balls are drawn. You have already mentioned it.

Comment: thanks for help

Comment: what is your name sir/madam?

Comment: You´re welcome. Here in the forum my name is just callculus. Sorry that I cannot be more specific. But what I can say that I´m male.

Comment: Ask your teacher **why** on earth he gave you that inconvenient advice.  The direct route is shorter and more elegant, as you will have noticed by now. In the best scenario for him he did it to test your ability to find the answer indirectly as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $X$ be the random variable for the number of blue drawn balls.

Then

$P(X=0)=\frac{5}{7}\cdot \frac{4}{6}=\frac{10}{21}$

> My teacher asked me to solve it by finding the probability that the
>   balls drawn are blue and then subtracting it from 1.

To calulate $P(X=0)$ this is not right, because

$P(X=0)+P(X=1)+P(X=2)=1$

Solving for $P(X=0)$

$P(X=0)=1-P(X=1)-P(X=2)$

$=1-2\cdot \frac{2}{7}\cdot \frac{5}{6}-\frac{2}{7}\cdot \frac{1}{6}=\frac{10}{21}$

Note that at $X=1$ you have two cases:

1. First ball blue, second ball red or green.
2. First ball red or green, second ball blue.

That´s why the middle summand has the additional factor $2$.

Answer (score 3):

Assumption: The first ball drawn is not put back in the bag.

Let E be the event that none of the two picked balls are blue. Further let $E_1$ and $E_2$ be the events that the first ball picked is not blue and the second ball picked is not blue respectively.

$P(E) = P(E_1 \cap E_2) = P(E_1)P(E_2 | E_1)$

$\implies P(E) = \left( {5 \choose 1}*1/7 \right) \left( {4 \choose 1}*1/6 \right)$

$\implies P(E) =  10/21 $

Answer (score 1):

You can also calculate the number of possible pairs of balls (assuming the ball is drawn and not thrown back in), which is $\binom{7}{2} = 21$ . Now calculate the number of possible pairs given only red and green ball. This gives us $\binom{5}{2}= 10$

So the probability is $\frac{\text{number of red and green ball pairs}}{\text{number of all possible pairs} }=\frac{10}{21}$

Answer (score 1):

Use multiplication rule to find the probability of not drawing the blue twice assuming without replacement.

\begin{equation}
P(\textit{draw red or green twice}) = \frac{5}{7} \cdot \frac{4}{6} = \frac{20}{42} = \frac{10}{21}. 
\end{equation}

Answer (score -1):

In a bag there are 4 red balls ,2green balls, and 3yellow balls .if two balls are drawn at random ,what is the probability that at least one of the balls is green in color.